# How can I join on a table twice and reference a column name differently each time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

So I have a situation where a table `Partners` has a one-to-one relationship with a table called `Regions` and also a one-to-many relationship with the same table  through an intersection table called `Destinations`. My nice naming conventions below should help you figure out what I mean.

```
        Regions
======================
 id | name 
======================
  1 | "United States"
  2 | "Mother Russia"
  3 | "Belize"

             Partners 
=================================
 id |    name      |  region_id
=================================
  1 |  "B Obama"   |     1
  2 |  "V Putin"   |     2 


         Destinations
==============================
  partner_id  | region_id 
==============================
       1      |     2
       1      |     3 
       2      |     1
       2      |     3
```

What I want is a query that returns a result like

```
=======================================================
  partner_name  | partner_region  | destination_region
=======================================================
   "B Obama"    | "United States" |  "Mother Russia"
   "B Obama"    | "United States" |  "Belize"
   "V Putin"    | "Mother Russia" |  "United States"
   "V Putin"    | "Mother Russia" |  "Belize"
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to join twice on the `Regions` table in order to make this query. I know that what I want is like

```
  SELECT Partners.name AS partner_name, 
         Regions.name AS partner_region, 
         ???          AS destination_region
  FROM 
      Partners INNER JOIN Regions ON Partners.region_id=Regions.id 
               INNER JOIN Destinations ON Partners.id=Destinations.partner_id
```

but what I'm confused on is what to fill in for `???` above because `Regions` is already joined to `Partners`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another `join`:

```
SELECT p.name AS partner_name, 
       rd.name AS partner_region, 
       rd.name AS destination_region
FROM Partners p INNER JOIN
     Regions rp
     ON p.region_id = rp.id INNER JOIN
     Destinations d
     ON p.id = d.partner_id INNER JOIN
     Regions rd
     ON d.region_id = rd.id;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 2):

You have to `JOIN` to `Regions` twice:

```
SELECT
    partner_name        = p.name,
    partner_region      = r.name,
    destination_region  = dr.name
FROM Partners p
INNER JOIN Regions r
    ON r.id = p.region_id
INNER JOIN Destinations d
    INNER JOIN Regions dr
        ON dr.id = d.region_id
    ON d.partner_id = p.id
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/476503)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add another join from Destinations to Regions again:

```
 SELECT Partners.name AS partner_name, 
         Regions.name AS partner_region, 
         Regions2.name AS destination_region
  FROM 
      Partners INNER JOIN Regions ON Partners.region_id=Regions.id 
               INNER JOIN Destinations ON Partners.id=Destinations.partner_id
               INNER JOIN Regions AS Regions2 on Destinations.region_id = Regions2.id
```

Note that I added a second alias to the Regions table named `Regions2`.  You need that alias so you can be unambiguous in telling the server which columns you want (e.g., `Regions2.name`).